# Intercept XHR requests and console.log the request headers and their values

Tags: javascript, request, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, request-headers

How do I intercept XHR requests and console.log the headers and their values? I have tried this:

```js
    const origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
            this.addEventListener('load', function() {
                console.log("open", this)
            });
        origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
```

but it doesn't give me the request headers, it only gives me the response headers.